# How to check if a hex number contains another hex number

Tags: python-3.x, hex, bitwise-operators

I been trying to accomplish something similar to the permission calculator of discord (like this one:  https://discordapi.com/permissions.html). I have used the bitwise operators of `combine_hex_number = hex_number | hex_number2` to combine the hex numbers. my question is, what bitwise operators do I need to use to check if `hex_number` is inside of `hex_number2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use `&`, the bitwise `AND`.

```py
if hex_number2 & hex_number == hex_number
```

If the original thing you "combined" into a number was a single bit (e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.) you just need `if hex_number2 & hex_number` because any result other than `0` will be what you are looking for.

**Why this works:**

The "combining" is actually a bit-wise `OR` operation, so for example if you'd do `5 | 19` (which gives `23`), you'd be looking at each bit in both numbers and if *one* of them is `1`, the resulting bit would also be `1` (otherwise `0`), like this:

```
 5   00000101 OR
19   00010011 =
-------------
23   00010111
```

If you do an `AND` operation, you do something similar, but each resulting bit is `1` if *both* of the input bits were `1`. So if you do `23 & 19` you'll get `19`, but if you'd do `23 & 36` you'll get `4`.

```
23   00010111 AND
19   00010011 =
-------------
19   00010011
```

```
23   00010111 AND
36   00100100 =
-------------
 4   00000100
```

So you can check by doing `if x & y == y`. (However, this works only with `y`'s that are exclusive to each other, bitwise, as in they don't share bits. Otherwise you'd get a false positive.)